# How to make use of fileglob & loop while copying files from source to destination with custom names

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Below is my set of reference data

```
id,firstname,secondname,department,subDepartment,salary
ID01,first01,surnam1,HR,pension,30000
ID02,first02,surnam2,IT,development,40000
ID03,first03,surnam3,IT,development,42000
ID04,first04,surnam4,IT,operations,46000
```

Below is my source directory which has random filenames

```bash
ls -1 /tmp/source/*/*

/tmp/source/HR/another_set.txt
/tmp/source/HR/rand02.txt
/tmp/source/HR/somethree.txt

/tmp/source/IT/33.txt
/tmp/source/IT/it01.txt
```

Final output required is to copy to `destination_directory` with the `source_directory` attached to filename

```bash
/tmp/dest/HR.another_set.txt
/tmp/dest/HR.rand02.txt
/tmp/dest/HR.somethree.txt
/tmp/dest/IT.33.txt
/tmp/dest/IT.it01.txt
```

Below is the playbook I tried

```yaml
---
- name: Copy files with appended directory name
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    destination_directory: "/tmp/dest"
    source_directory: "/tmp/source"
    reference_csv: "./configs/02_names_department.csv"
  tasks:
    - name: Read CSV file
      read_csv:
        path: "{{ reference_csv }}"
      register: csv_data

    - name: Create destination folder
      file:
        path: "{{ destination_directory }}"
        state: directory

    - name: Perform actual file copy
      copy:
        src: "{{ source_directory }}/{{ item.department }}/{{ item.file }}"
        # For the `dest`, I couldn't find a way use the original filename. 
        # Hence I'm putting `item.id`. 
        # But, what is needed is the original filename
        dest: "{{ destination_directory }}/{{ item.department }}.{{ item.id }}.txt"
      loop: "{{ csv_data.list }}"
      vars:
        item:
          id: "{{ item.1.id }}"
          department: "{{ item.1.department }}"
          file: "{{ lookup('fileglob', source_directory + '/' + item.1.department + '/*.txt') | first }}"
```

I can do in an ugly way of getting this into a `registered_list` using `find`, but, is there are any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Your file structure won't fit this limitation of the `fileglob` lookup:

> Patterns are only supported on files, not directory/paths.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fileglob_lookup.html#notes*</sup>

---

But, you could use the [`filetree`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/filetree_lookup.html) lookup instead and only target the files with the help of a [`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) filter.

```yaml
- copy:
    src: "{{ item.src }}"
    dest: "{{ destination_directory }}/{{ new_filename }}"
  loop: >-
    {{ 
      query('filetree', source_directory) 
        | selectattr('state', '==', 'file') 
    }}
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ new_filename }}"
  vars:
    new_filename: "{{ item.path | dirname }}.{{ item.path | basename }}"

    destination_directory: /tmp/dest
    source_directory: /tmp/source
```

Which yields:

```yaml
TASK [copy] **************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=HR.another_set.txt)
changed: [localhost] => (item=HR.somethree.txt)
changed: [localhost] => (item=HR.rand02.txt)
changed: [localhost] => (item=IT.it01.txt)
changed: [localhost] => (item=IT.33.txt)
```

This code won't scale well if you have nested folders, i.e.:

```
/tmp/source/IT/SEC/file.txt
```

But could be adapted using a [`replace`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html) filter:

```yaml
new_filename: "{{ item.path | replace('/', '.') }}"
```

Giving

```
/tmp/dest/IT.SEC.file.txt
```

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately, filetree not present in office ansible as it is not part of core. But voted up